# Tcl proc call in foreach loop - efficiency

Tags: list, foreach, return, tcl, proc

In my Tcl code, I currently have a proc that returns a Tcl list.
I'm calling this proc in foreach loop as shown

```
foreach a [get_objects] {
    # ...
}
```

How efficient is it with respect to Tcl? 
Is the following style better?

```
set my_list [get_objects]
foreach a $my_list {
    # ...
}
```

FYI, the list's length is pretty large.

Comment: Technically, you are not calling your list-generating proc *in*, but rather *ahead* of the foreach loop. In both cases, there will just be one copy of the list and not multiple ones, and each iteration will just work on one list element. Do you perceive any concrete problem? In this shape (aside from one extra assignment), I expect the snippets to perform very similar.

Comment: Also note that in your second snippet, it should be `set my_list [get_objects]`

Comment: This is a guess: I think that in the first snippet, the memory used for the list will be released (or be eligible for cleanup) after the loop finishes, while the 2nd snippet will have to hold on to that memory due to the variable referencing it (unless you subsequently unset my_list).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the first one is slower. 
Tcl does not have compiler, due to this fact the program just "flows" without any smart memory allocations. 
As interpreted works, it cannot delete $my_list because it does not know the next code line, maybe the variable will be used. 
Probably, without knowing how Tcl interpreter, the first option will release the memory which is allocated for [get_objects]. Due to this action it will consume more time.